# Nimclient command failed

Tags: aix

Below error is observed for nimclient command.

```
# nimclient -l -l `hostname -s`
<hostname>: Connection timed out
0042-006 nimclient: (To_Master) rcmd Connection timed out
```

Any resolution for this issue?

Comment: I think you should build some network-connection between client and server.

Comment: Do you have NIM server run on this machine? Have you check if something listen on 1058, 1059, 3901, 3902?